# Tutorials on how to customize an Android User Interface

Tags: android, user-interface

I have just finished building a simple application for Android. It uses the standard components (views) that are included in the Android SDK. Now I want my application to look good, i.e. customize my UI.

Do you know about any good tutorials explaining how to do this? I'm looking for short simple articles, nothing more, nothing less :)

One thing I have noticed when I google for "android UI tutorials" is that a lot of the "tutorials" I find only contains code of how to do things, no images showing what the code will result in. As I have no previous experience of using the code it is very hard visualize what the code will result in. Thus I would be very happy if you could recommend tutorials with awesome looking images.

Thanks!

/Gustav

Comment: Basic, but without pictures: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

Answer (score 5):

You can try the following links for customizing your UI:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui    (This should obviously be your prime target)

http://www.anddev.org/tutorial_ui_themes-t4367.html

http://marakana.com/forums/android/general/240.html

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-ui-fundamentals-challenge-linearlayout/

There are many eBooks available too.
Happy Coding!
Best Luck!